# Assign a string to constant struct

Tags: c, string, struct

I have the following struct,

```
struct example_struct { 
     int number ;
     char word[100] 
}
```

Which I initialize in my code as a constant struct

```
const struct example_struct example {
    .number = 5
} ;
strcpy(example.word, "some_string") ;
```

which gives me the warning when I try to compile my code:

"warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type"

I realize that I shouldn't be trying to assign a value of a struct when I make it a const struct, but I can't put the stringcpy inside the struct either. Is there any way I can assign a string to an element of a const struct in c?

Comment: You could create a non-const instance and use that as the initializer for the const, if you happen to be using non literal strings. Just remember to initialize/assign the entire array before that.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Are you saying I could create a non-const instance of the string or the struct?

Comment: Of the struct, copy over the string, and use the non const struct as the initializer of the const struct. But it's rather pointless, if you're initializing from a string literal, as shown in the answer you've accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning is correct - since you declared your `struct with`const` qualifier, copying data into it at runtime is undefined behavior.

You could either drop the qualifier, or initialize your `struct` like this:

```
const struct example_struct example = {
    .number = 5
,   .word = "some_string"
};
```

This would put a null-terminated sequence of characters from `"some_string"` into the initial portion of the `word[100]` array, and fill the rest of it with `'\0'` characters.

Comment: How do you derive this idea that with designated initializer we can do this with string literal? ( I have a guess how did you derive that but still I want to hear it from you).

Comment: @coderredoc I tried this before :-) Generally, though, C compiler allows "mix-and-match" in lots of places, so if you can do something with a scalar variable initializer, you should be able to do it with designated initializer as well.

Comment: Aren't the rules for aggregate initialization recursive ([6.7.9p20](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p20))?